# How To Create Custom Page Template With Collapsible Panels

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, visualforce-template, page-template

In the Lightning App UI, I'm working in a Case Record Page (Page Type = Record Page, Object = Case), that looks like this:

[image]

I want the left and right panels (the case info and knowledge search) to be collapsible so that the middle section can be full width if desired. How can I accomplish this?

Can I create a custom page template (currently you can see it's using the "Three Regions" one)? Is there a better way?

Comment: You need to create a template component using `aura:component`. and you can implement the collapse function inside the custom template.

Comment: @RahulGawale - right, but once I create that component (through the UI I guess?), is it supposed to show up in the list of templates (when I click the "Change" button next to the Template field in the screenshot above)?

Comment: yes [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_app_builder_template_component.htm) is how you can create that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to implement the collapsible split view in standard detail pages or to be able to create custom layout.

However, you can create a dirty approach,

1. you put a button on Account detail page
2. Update a boolean on Account - (hide sidebars or something)
3. Add Component Visibility Filters in both Left and Right side bars and refer to the account custom field that you created in step 2.

If user wants to hide the side bars, they click the button and it updates the custom field which in return hides the component.

Comment: This is likely not a scalable option if more than 1 user views the same Case record

Comment: Likely. But a possible solution until OP can get another options.